# Getting a vector from an angle and length?

Tags: c#, vector, xna

I'm working on a monster's sight(cone-shaped) and need a way to draw it. The vector I get from the angle/distance will be centered around a position(the monster's position).

- **Using C#/Xna, how can I get a vector if I have an angle and distance(length from position)?**

The answer helped lead me in the right direction. Code now looks like:

```
Vector2 vector = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(angle) * distance + position.X, (float)Math.Sin(angle) * distance + position.Y);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use some trigonometry.

Like so, assuming that `angle` is your angle, in radians:

```
new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(angle), (float)Math.Sin(angle));
```

However, if you want an angle in degrees, then you'd use `MathHelper.ToRadians`, like this:

```
float angleInRadians = MathHelper.ToRadians(angle);
new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(angleInRadians), (float)Math.Sin(angleInRadians));
```